Can I make a transaction from a wallet to another using a Solidity Smart Contract through their addresses?
I am making an allowance system, where a Provider sets an allowance for the receiver. The receiver can then make transactions that are directly deducted from the provider's wallet balance.
My project has 3 smart contracts. main.sol, provider.sol and allowance.sol
Basically when I call the Transact() function in main.sol, it should call a payable function in provider.sol that makes the transaction from the provider wallet to the recipient wallet.
Here's the code for main.sol for reference:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./provider.sol";
import "./allowance.sol";

contract MainContract{
    struct Receivers{
        address ProviderAddress;
        address contractAddress;
    }

    mapping(address => address) public providers;
    mapping(address => Receivers) public receivers;

    function RegisterProvider(address _providerWallet) external {
        ProviderContract newProvider = new ProviderContract();
        newProvider.initialize(_providerWallet);
        providers[_providerWallet] = address(newProvider);
    }

    function RegisterAllowance(address _providerAddress, address _walletAddress, uint _amount, uint _startdate, uint _enddate,  string memory _rName) external {
        address providerContractAddress = providers[_providerAddress];
        require(providerContractAddress != address(0), "Provider contract not found");
        
        AllowanceContract newAllowance = new AllowanceContract();
        newAllowance.initialize(_providerAddress, _walletAddress, _amount, _startdate, _enddate, _rName);

        ProviderContract providerContractInstance = ProviderContract(providerContractAddress);

        // Call the addAllowance function of the ProviderContract instance
        providerContractInstance.addAllowance(_walletAddress, _amount, _startdate, _enddate, _rName);

        
        receivers[_walletAddress] = Receivers({
            ProviderAddress: _providerAddress,
            contractAddress: address(newAllowance)
        });
    }
    
    function Transact(address _recipientAddress, uint256 _amount, address _behalfAddress) external payable {
        // Get the ProviderAddress and contractAddress using the _behalfAddress
        Receivers memory receiver = receivers[_behalfAddress];
        address providerAddress = receiver.ProviderAddress;
        address allowanceContractAddress = receiver.contractAddress;

        // Ensure that the receiver's contractAddress is valid
        require(allowanceContractAddress != address(0), "Allowance contract not found");

        // Cast the contract addresses to their respective contract types
        ProviderContract providerContractInstance = ProviderContract(providerAddress);
        AllowanceContract allowanceContractInstance = AllowanceContract(allowanceContractAddress);

        // Call the Transact function of the AllowanceContract
        allowanceContractInstance.Transact(_amount);

        // Call the Transact function of the ProviderContract to make the payment
            

        address payable payableRecipient = payable(_recipientAddress);
        providerContractInstance.payRecipient(payableRecipient, _amount);
    }

    function getProviderData(address _providerAddress) external view returns (uint256, ProviderContract.Benefactor[] memory, ProviderContract.Allowance[] memory, ProviderContract.Transaction[] memory) {
        // Retrieve the contract address from the mapping
        address providerContractAddress = providers[_providerAddress];
        require(providerContractAddress != address(0), "Provider contract not found");

        // Create an instance of the ProviderContract
        ProviderContract providerContractInstance = ProviderContract(providerContractAddress);

        // Call the getProviderData function of the ProviderContract
        return providerContractInstance.getProviderData();
    }

}

and here are the Transaction functions from provider.sol:
function Transact(address _recipient, uint _amount, address _benefactorAddress) external payable {
        string memory behalfName = benefactors[_benefactorAddress];

        // Create a new transaction
        Transaction memory newTransaction = Transaction({
            amount: _amount,
            recipient: _recipient,
            timestamp: block.timestamp,
            behalf: behalfName
        });

        // Push the transaction into the transactions array
        transactions.push(newTransaction);

        // Find the corresponding allowance
        for (uint i = 0; i < allowances.length; i++) {
            if (allowances[i].walletAddress == _recipient) {
                // Update the allowance spent
                allowances[i].allowanceSpent += _amount;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function payRecipient(address payable _recipientAddress, uint256 _amount) external payable {
        _recipientAddress.transfer(_amount);
    }

Now I know this is kinda impossible to do, so I am looking for a workaround, can I just initiate the transaction in the start and then have the provider sign the transaction so it goes through? Or can I actually call a function that can do this fund transfer?
Basically main.sol deploys a Provider.sol contract for every provider that is registered, and I want to initiate the fund transfer from that smart contract and the funds should be deducted from the provider's wallet. Even if the provider has to authorize it after it is initiated, it would be fine. Can this be done?
